# Object recognition Using sift descriptors

Tags: opencv, sift, object-recognition

I am a newbie to the field. My problem is to recognize whether an object similar to the object used in training images(Images of Similar objects) is present in test image or not. I want to use SIFT descriptors for recognition. Is the bag of words approach by clustering of SIFT descriptors which is used for object classification into different classes is suitable for it or if there is simpler approach using sift descriptors for it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bag of visual words (BoW) is indeed the classic approach, originally proposed by Sivic & Zisserman in 2003 [[Paper](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/papers/sivic03.pdf)]. It was among the first to depart from previous methods that favored global descriptors as opposed to local features like SIFT and SURF. I do recommend continuing to implement this classic pipeline if you are just beginning to learn about object detection and recognition.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Please let me know if there is a good implementation guide preferably in c++.

Comment: Check out the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library. They have an example under `samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp` [ [link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matcher_simple.cpp) ] for SIFT matching and also BoW classification under `samples/cpp/bagofwords_classification.cpp` [ [link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/bagofwords_classification.cpp) ].

Comment: apologies for once again disturbing you but i tried this implementation of bag of words but it always produces it shows the same result each time for any kind of evaluation data. I am not able to figure out where the problem lies.I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Actually code exceeds the maximum no. of characters permissible to comment.can you please provide me your email id.